# Flume 1.6 compatibility with ElasticSearch 2.3.1

Tags: elasticsearch, flume

I am trying to use flume to dump data into ElasticSearch but getting below error:

```
org.elasticsearch.transport.RemoteTransportException: Failed to deserialize exception response from stream
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportSerializationException: Failed to deserialize exception response from stream
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.handlerResponseError(MessageChannelHandler.java:171)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.messageReceived(MessageChannelHandler.java:125)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:560)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:787)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:462)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:443)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:303)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:560)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:555)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:107)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:312)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:88)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: Unsupported version: 1
        at org.elasticsearch.common.io.ThrowableObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ThrowableObjectInputStream.java:46)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:299)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.io.ThrowableObjectInputStream.<init>(ThrowableObjectInputStream.java:38)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.handlerResponseError(MessageChannelHandler.java:168)
```

Does anyone know if Flume 1.6 is compatible with ElasticSearch 2.3.1?

I was not able to confirm from below page:
https://flume.apache.org/

Answer (score 1):

Since changes to the transport layer on ElasticSearch 2.x branch
Flume is not compatible.
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/14187

You can use the lastest version of elasticsearch compatible (1.7.5):
https://www.elastic.co/downloads/past-releases/elasticsearch-1-7-5

Comment: If Flume depends on ES 0.90, it's just luck that it works with 1.7.5. **The Elasticsearch team doesn't test mixed versions** so some functionality might work between 0.90 and 1.7 and some might not. If one decides to use 0.90 with 1.7 it is at his own risk.

Comment: Yes, you're right, it's certainly lucky, but I confirm that flume works like a charm with elasticsearch version 1.7.5

Comment: Cool. Nice find about the github issue. +1

Comment: I found this custom sink for ES > 2.0 https://github.com/lucidfrontier45/ElasticsearchSink2 Has anyone tried it? I am going to try this tonight and will post results

Comment: I tried the custom sink above and it worked. Thanks guys for the help!! We moved data from syslogtcp to elasticsearch. We used Flume 1.5 version(I assume it will work with 1.6 as well) and ElasticSearch 2.3.1

Answer (score 0):

Even Flume 1.7-SNAPSHOT (the latest) is depending on a very old version of Elasticsearch: 0.90.1.

Take a look in their git repo [here](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=flume.git;a=blob_plain;f=pom.xml;hb=trunk) at the `pom.xml` file used to build Flume. More specifically this line:

```
<elasticsearch.version>0.90.1</elasticsearch.version>
```

Most likely will not work with anything in the 1.x or 2.x versions of ES.

Answer (score 0):

Officially Flume 1.6 doesn't work with ElasticSearch 2.x . However there is a custom sink available which allows them to integrate. Refer below git URL for the same:

https://github.com/lucidfrontier45/ElasticsearchSink2